# move to another activity using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android library, I gave the user an edittext to enter the name of an activity , and I should move to it, In other words I dont know all the activities of the android app

```
String name_activity=Activityedit.getText();
Intent in=new Intent(Dform.this, ? );
```

What I should do to move the app to the activity with " name_activity"
Thank's

Solution :

```
String intent_redirect=getPackageName()+"."+Activityedit.getText();
                Class<?> c = null;
                  try {
                    c = Class.forName(intent_redirect);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent in =new Intent(DialForm.this,c);
                startActivity(in);
```

Comment: And what about your All activities? have you register in your `manifest.xml` ?

Comment: it's a library , so the user should register it in his manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
Class cls=Activityedit.class;
Intent in=new Intent(Dform.this, cls );
startActivity(in);
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I getting this right? You want to create an activity during runtime? This is impossible afaik. And why would you want to do this?

Comment: you are absolutely right. +1

Comment: Your answer looks like a comment to me.

Comment: Well you might be right in some regards. But it is the simple answer to his question that it is not possible. He could just accept it and close this question.

Comment: @ZerO weil, what's the reason for your judgment?

Comment: @Mighter what judgment?

Comment: @ZerO you say it's impossible. What's the reason for that? Can you support your claim?

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT possible, you Cannot cast from String to Class.

Comment: please check the edit , it is possible , thank you